# How to have text for dynamically generated checkboxes?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkedlistbox

I would like to generate checkboxes dynamically in a checkedlist. I generate the .Text of each checkbox from a list of strings, then I add each new checkbox to the checkedlist, when I run the application, they are there, but there is no text.

[image: No text for the checkbox]

I've tried to use the Controls to get the text, but I only had one checkbox each time where I want the complete list of the string. So, I return to this method :

`

```
public void GetAttributs()
        {
            CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();

            List<string> lstAttributs = new List<string>();
            
            lstAttributs.Add("Alifère: capacité de voler à x mètres d'altitude");
            lstAttributs.Add("Amphibien: capacité de nager à x mètres de profondeur, peut respirer sous l'eau et sur la terre");
            lstAttributs.Add("Armure naturelle: peau épaisse, jusqu'à x% de dégâts physiques absorbés par l'ennemi");
            lstAttributs.Add("Avantage du terrain: sur x terrain(s), la créature n'a pas de malus");
            lstAttributs.Add("Célérité: attaque toujours en premier lors de tour d'initiative");
            lstAttributs.Add("Corps artificiels: créature artificielle, nul besoin pour elle de respirer");
            lstAttributs.Add("Dégagement: impossible d'être encerclé");
            lstAttributs.Add("Double frappe: capacité d'attaquer deux fois par tour de jeu");
            lstAttributs.Add("Fin limier: plafond supplémentaire de 5% dans une des compétences techniques");
            lstAttributs.Add("Frigifugé: capacité de survivre à basse température jusqu'à x degrés Celsius");
            lstAttributs.Add("Gros dormeur: temps de récupération divisé par deux lors de repos");
            lstAttributs.Add("Hyperesthésie: chance de ne pas être empoisonné égale à x%");
            lstAttributs.Add("Ignifugé: capacité de survivre à haute température jusqu'à x degrés Celsius");
            lstAttributs.Add("Insubmersible: impossible d'être submergé");
            lstAttributs.Add("Lourdaud: trop lourd pour attaquer en premier, attaque en dernier");
            lstAttributs.Add("Mithridatisation: chance de ne pas être empoisonné égale à x%");
            lstAttributs.Add("Mort-vivant: ne peut pas être soigné par des moyens conventionnels (sauf repos), est obligé de dévorer un corps ou boire des fluides corporels");
            lstAttributs.Add("Porteur de charges lourdes: capacité de porter 25% la charge maximum que l'on peut porter");
            lstAttributs.Add("Prodige: plafond supplémentaire de 5% dans une des compétences naturelles");
            lstAttributs.Add("Régénération spirituelle: à chaque début de tour, 10% de l'énergie est régénérée par le lanceur");
            lstAttributs.Add("Régénération vitale: à chaque début de tour, 10% de PV régénérés pour le lanceur");
            lstAttributs.Add("Soif de bataille: plafond supplémentaire de 5% dans une des compétences de combat");
            lstAttributs.Add("Souffle: la créature est capable de cracher du feu ou n'importe quel autre élément (dégâts non magiques)");
            lstAttributs.Add("Vague de panique: fais trop peur, les adversaires doivent réussir un jet de Volonté tous les x tour(s) pour agir, mais peuvent toujours esquiver en cas d'échec");
            lstAttributs.Add("Voie libre: capacité de déplacement doublée lorsque le terrain est dégagé.");

            for(int i = 0; i < lstAttributs.Count; i++)
            {
                checkBox.Text = lstAttributs[i];
                chckLstAttributs.Items.Add(checkBox);
            }
        }
```

`

Comment: It doesn't look right that you allocate `CheckBox` only once, and use it for all list items.

Comment: I thought the value would change with each new iteration of the loop, should I store them in a list of checkboxes and make a second loop that goes through that list?

Comment: See @jmcilhinney's answer below. You don't really need `CheckBox`s to add  `CheckedListBox` items. My comment above was just a suspicion based on the fact that you tried to add them to the control.

Answer (score 1):

You don't add `CheckBox` controls to a `CheckedListBox`. A `CheckedListBox` is basically just a tarted up `ListBox`. You add items to the `CheckedListBox` and the control displays them, just like a `ListBox`. The difference is that the `CheckedListBox` displays a check box next to each item. Just do this:

```cs
chckLstAttributs.Items.AddRange(lstAttributs);
```